# Organizing code in HTML

Tags: html, pragma

So I'm self studying HTML and I was wondering if there's a way to organize my code in a better way, like when you use pragma region and pragma endregion in C++.
I'm really looking for something to be as simple as that, to be 2 or maybe 3 code lines at best.
For those who doesn't know C++, pragma is used like this:

```
#pragma region NameOfMyRegion
// Code....
#pragma endregion
```

And then you can just expand and collapse it as you wish, and the name of the region will be what is displayed instead of the whole bunch of code section in the region. The example is in this link: http://pho.to/9Z7LB

Looking for something as super simple, because I only know C++ and just started HTML.

Comment: If you have an semi advanced text editor, you can fold and expand elements.

Comment: There is no `#pragma region` in C++. That's a [Microsoft specific extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944.aspx).

Comment: I'm using VS13, so that's maybe the reason I can use it. I can't fold and expand sections that are either not in brackets or are 2 or more lines that are marked as comments.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist in pure html but it does in javascript (which can be embedded in a script tag). Javascript can be used to inject HTML into your page so through this method people often embed HTML indirectly via imported javascript.

In ES6 one of the newer versions of Javascript you can use '[import](https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/)':

```
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

Example would point to a file called example.js which would export its functions using a model like.

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
```

Example from: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Because ES6 isn't universally used by all browsers many people use a pre-compiler which compiles modern ES6 javascript code into an older version of javascript. A common tool for this is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).